# Rails 3.1 - calling AJAX request twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
<%=link_to 'Add note', {:controller => 'home', :action => 'add_note', :id =>user.id}, :remote => true%>
```

After click on this link is called the page **_add_note.html.erb** (via JS **add_note.js.erb**). This file looks this:

```
$('div#ajax_div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('add_note')) %>");
```

It looks good, after click on the link above is loaded to the **ajax_div** a content of the file **_add_note.html.erb**.

But the problem is, that after click on the link I see in Firebug, that the ajax call is processed twice.

```
GET /home/add_note?id=39 200 OK 601ms   
GET /home/add_note?id=39 200 OK 1154ms
```

How it is possible? What could be wrong?

Comment: Is all other javascript and Ajax behaving normally?  Perhaps you've included the rails.js twice somehow, assigning the link handler 2x?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand how the assets in Rails 3.1 works. Because in the /app/assets/javasripts I have only the file **application.js**, that is empty and in the application.html.erb I have **<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>**. If I take a look to the source of HTML page, I see there **<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>** and **<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>**. But in my directories these files aren't.

Comment: Check out the documentation on [the assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which is new to Rails 3.1.  The jQuery and UJS javascripts are included via gems, and can be seen in your `Gemfile`.  But unfortunately, if all you're seeing for javascript includes are those two files, it probably isn't an issue of any handler being included 2x.

Comment: That's weird... the same code works my fine in a project in Rails 3.

Answer (score 4):

This likely has to do with the assets pipeline, although the [asset pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) wasn't very useful here. You might have application*.js.* included twice in the asset path. Run:

```
$ find . -name "application*.js*"
./app/assets/javascripts/application.js
./public/assets/application.js
./public/assets/application-5f5e14d05ab99cac084b66cb87bbeec8.js
./public/assets/application-5f5e14d05ab99cac084b66cb87bbeec8.js.gz
./public/assets/application-95fca227f3857c8ac9e7ba4ffed80386.js.gz
./public/assets/application-95fca227f3857c8ac9e7ba4ffed80386.js
./public/assets/application.js.gz
```

If you see a picture as above, delete the generated assets from `public/assets`.

Answer (score 0):

When you include js twice it will call two times